# Generic type not working with Parent Class

Tags: typescript

Any typescript experts here can look into this code and guide me what is wrong here?

I have a `ParentSchema` which holds common fields in DB. So that other schemas can extend the `ParentSchema`.

Also I have a `ModelService` class which contains common DB functions (eg: update). `ModelService` accept a Model as generic type.

There is another `MongoJob` class which I will pass to `ModelService` function with required details. The same generic type from `ModelService` is passing to `MongoJob` also from `ModelService.update()` function.

```
/* ParentSchema to hold common properties */
export class ParentSchema {
    id!: string;
}

/* MongoJob to hold properties to run job */
export interface MongoJob<T extends ParentSchema> {
    /**
     * primary key value of the model
     */
    id?: number | string;
    /**
     * body object used for create or update
     */
    body?: Partial<T>;
}
export class MongoJob<T extends ParentSchema> {
    constructor(job: MongoJob<T>) {
        this.id = job.id;
        this.body = job.body || {};
    }
}

/* ModelService to hold common methods */
export class ModelService<M extends ParentSchema> {

    constructor() { }

    async update(job: MongoJob<M>): Promise<any> {
        try {
            console.log(job);
            const response = {}; // call db functions
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            return { error };
        }
    }
}

/* Country model */
export class Country extends ParentSchema {
    name!: string;
}

/* Calling functions using Country model */
const service = new ModelService<Country>();

/* Working */
service.update(
    new MongoJob<Country>({
        id: 1,
        body: {
            name: 'Demo'
        },
    })
);

/* Working */
service.update(
    new MongoJob({
        id: 1,
        body: {},
    })
);

/* Not Working */
service.update(
    new MongoJob({
        id: 1,
        body: {
            name: 'Demo'
        }, // Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ParentSchema>'.
    })
);
```

`new MongoJob()` is not working when body is not empty and without passing `<Country>` as generic type, `<Country>` is already passing in `new ModelService()`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBACghgTgpgOwC4GUDGALOBbKYkD2YGBANgCZhoHbYEJgAOMBjcMSAlnAM5gjAAUHAAejAhyqkoPPtHjJ0WXGADegsJrCdyAQgBcYHkhicEAcwDcggL6DBoMAFl65ggCkCAI3xESFJhY2Dm4%20QjAYAFcGACtvfiFRcUkzJHYAMyg0OGdXD28AHgAVMFE0hHI5WERUTBwoAD41DS1QEBatcGZOXBgATzAAazgBgDcoUkicgnT8LDA6cjhSDs0BVZ0AfkMESOwvdjAAHyMTMytVttX%20MC8CcgHvGLg0JDBInjhKdIkqeCg0mBfpFGOQAXBrustLd7n1tpBYFwJsUGtY7EkJG80NJZLkLPkvMVSiJypUEQpaspGs1odQEMYoq8JAAKOJeQwufGeQlFBoAShp0K0SAwnB4ADodGAALxgNmS8jWIXC0USu4PGVy7zi9UDI4nVQ2JVaOx2BzgFxLUgodijTjZXzEMiUai0egLOAi%2058dYYyTYmR8S3LG0wO3ZApOYmkqoUpT1JrqVZ0hmRJkwZkC1RgM3QmR9BBod6g8Gs7wcvLcyP8wwQFjYMVwApQBB9RPXYX9QXK2n0HhkODi0gEcxlrx8409rQpt7wHjiek5WWGyxgYDAKgTUhgcg%20dLRV6cPsd5XwJCRGAMOcLz6ToU2TdITBgZnsFgwLMnoVni8MbNv34jS-OxoVNexHAAYQIaITAGRZlgSYQxExKRAzAKCYK7MpEDJeQanjFR1GhBAoGwOADFOUwLDRcDwAgrdzjAfdCy4Pt3h4RiMOQLt4O3dYZyMW17SXMAEDgAB3XIrVDcMmy42CGkzaxzTAAB1CRBkY9ZPjDYTxRBME0mZVYxMkzk3CreT%20kUoiex0QwAEYABov11QxbKnTQSLIwwAHIABEcAIXzgJc0C%20UECdaLUjStKEHTZP0ksjJMiS8Qs7xmQ8oV7LAZzXNhdybDCk0IqilSADkCDedSYE0ixEISvSDNLVKzMrTLsuhXL8qnNzu087y4D8wK6BCqditWGwyssIA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG8Oow) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new MongoJob( ... )` without a generic, you are getting the default generic value, which is `ParentSchema` because of your generic constraint in your class declaration (`class MongoJob<T extends ParentSchema>`).

---

This:

```
foo.bar(new Baz());
```

is comparable to this:

```
const baz = new Baz();
foo.bar(baz);
```

Not that it is treating `new Baz()` as a variable when instantiated inline, but the instance itself is created independent of the method to which it is passed: there is no opportunity for contextual type inference in this scenario.

This is different than declaring an object literal, which does gain type inference. One option would be to create the instance within the method:

```
class Foo<T> {
  bar(obj: T) {
    const baz = new Baz<T>(obj);
    // ...
  }
}

// Expected type inference will work here: 
foo.bar({ fizz: 'buzz' });
```

Read more about type inference in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).